# LiveCode: Running in Edit Mode

Tags: ide, livecode

I am running the Windows version of LiveCode. My issue is that when I try to open the script editor, or even move any objects the coding environment treats my actions as if they are being performed in RunMode (LiveCode version of debug). Without the ability to enter "Edit Mode" I am unable to work on my program. I have invested a good amount of time researching but every link to a forum with a similar question is inaccessible. If you know what the problem is and/or how to fix it, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: There isn't a run mode or edit mode. The pointer tool allows you to edit the program while the browse tool allows you to use the program. Any scripts that you have added to your stack stay available all the time and can be triggered any time, unless you turn off messages (see the Messages button in the tool bar). If you can explain _why_ exactly this is a problem for you, perhaps I can provide you with a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

also, you can check in your application browser that the "selectable" column doesn't have selectability turned off for an object.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things can cause this condition.

1. Your stack might have somehow been set to "modeless". Try this from the message box:

   topLevel this stack
2. The cantmodify property of your stack may be set to true. Check it in the property inspector or do this in the message box:

   set the cantModify of this stack to false